# How to disable the cceditbox moving the whole scene to accommodate a keyboard

Tags: cocos2d-x, editbox

I've used the editbox in my game to handle the input.But there is a thing done by the system that the whole game scene is moved up to accommodate the soft keyboard.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: OK, I got it.In ios,You can just comment the "[eaglview doAnimationWhenKeyboardMoveWithDuration:duration distance:distance];" in the CCEditBoxImplIOS.mm file.